# How to open a pane in a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

HI i want to open a pane in a JOptionPane, i have buttons on the pane,

```
 PPane newPane = new PPane(); 
 int choose = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, newPane, "Message...",
 JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

now i can open my pane in a JOptionPane but there is a "ok" button, i dont want this, i just want open my pane,

or

```
Object[] options = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Click OK to continue", "Warning",
JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
null, options, options[0]);
```

if i dont put buttons on my pane, i open the JOptionPane with OK and Cancel button, now can i put my pane this??

Comment: Start accepting answers for previous questions (http://stackoverflow.com/q/23109192/131872) if you want help with future questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can not put your pane in a JOptionpane dialog,

I would suggest rather writing your own JDialog and put your pane on there. 
You can still make your Dialog model by using the correct constructor:

```
public JDialog(Frame owner, boolean modal)
```

Here is a small example of a custom Dialog:

http://darksleep.com/player/DialogExample/

Comment: yes i can use jdialog but i call this in my JInternalFrame so i cant use JDialog cuz JDialog(frame, modal) needs frame not internalframe,

Comment: Ah i see what you mean, um maby try the link. Also if you want you can dig into the java code and see how it displays a model dialog ontop of a internal jframe:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420276/display-a-modal-dialog-box-in-a-jinternalframe-without-pausing-application